# How do you change the Excel StatusBar message using Office.js?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to figure out how to change the status message in excel using the office.js Excel Add-in.  I wouldnt think this would be too hard but cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done programmatically with Office.js. One potential alternative is to pop a toast on your add-in itself. We have a helper function you can use and looks like:

```js
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {

        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify("Whatever text you need");

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Please also upvote/create a new request in our https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: The problem i am having is that when i click one of our buttons in the ribbon.  It changes the statusbar message to say "Office is working on your Get Data".  This button pops up a dialog and i want to remove that text when you close that dialog.

Comment: so there is no way to do this?  I just want to remove the message when i cancel out of the dialog.

Comment: there is no API for this, currently

Comment: @Seth Make sure `event.completed()` is being called [in your command function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands?view=office-js#step-5-add-the-functionfile-element) to signal that processing has completed. That should make the message go away.